# How do I ensure that my AutoResetEvent methods are called in the right order?

Tags: c#, timer, autoresetevent

I have some code that needs to run a Timer.  The Timer checks for a condition and, based on the result, signals to the caller that it can continue.  Here's my pseudocode:

```
class MyClass
{
    private AutoResetEvent _reset;
    private System.Threading.Timer _timer;

    public void Run()
    {
        this._reset = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        this._timer = new System.Threading.Timer(this.TimerStep, null, 0, 1000);

        this._reset.WaitOne(); //wait for condition() to be true

        this._reset.Dispose();
        this._timer.Dispose();
    }

    private void TimerStep(object arg)
    {
        if(condition())
        {
            this._reset.Set(); //should happen after the _reset.WaitOne() call
        }
    }
}
```

My concern has to do with how I'm instantiating the Timer.  If I start it with a 0 dueTime, the comments say that the timer will start immediately.  What happens if the calling thread gets preempted by the timer and the `this._reset.Set()` call happens before the calling thread has a chance to call `this._reset.WaitOne()`?  Is this something I have to worry about?  So far in my testing the code works like I'd expect.

Note that I set up the code in this way because I want to block the `Run()` function until `condition()` is true, but I only want to check `condition()` every second or so.

Comment: In this case, it doesn't matter which one happens first. `_reset` starts unsignaled and so the `WaitOne` will halt. Once the condition is met it will be released. If the condition is met and the `_reset` is released before the `WaitOne` call, it will just not halt.

Comment: Does this mean that the order in which I call `WaitOne()` and `Set()` doesn't matter?

Comment: Yes. It says so exactly.

Comment: I see.  I was having trouble figuring out the terminology that they use on the MSDN AutoResetEvent page.  Thanks.